# Power Query; Calculating when a certain value in numerical order is missing and creating an additional row

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, power-query, transform

Hello Fellow Super Users,

I generate a report every week that identifies demands for parts that my company makes for the current week and future weeks. The report I generate loads data from a customer file which I download, transform and load into my report using Power Query. The report shows the weeknumber for the year and the demand for that week. The problem I am facing is the customer report skips a week (week 26) and goes straight to 27 (View attached images).

What steps can I take in Power Query to calculate when a week # is missing and create an additional row for that weeknumber and fill it with "0".

I have attached images of my table generated from PQ and of the PQ table itself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a new Row with empty data but list 26 Week in Table? If yes, I think you can create a new table with one Row you need and add to Power Query, then Append them.

Comment: This question has been solved on Stack Overflow, thank you for your input!

Comment: Answer to my question is on the link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448917/power-query-calculating-when-a-certain-value-in-numerical-order-is-missing-and/54466226#54466226